# How to downgrade my rails version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails version 4.2.0. How can I downgrade to  version 3.2.19?

I tried the following:

1. I opened command prompt.
2. I typed `gem uninstall rails`
3. Some options came for rails version then I selected my current version and pressed entered.
4. Then  typed  `gem install rails -v 3.2.19` for installing this version.
5. I went to my Site directory and typed `rails new blog`
6. When I opened the Gemfile of blog application I found again Rails version 4.2.0 is present there.

Comment: why do you just not create a new rails space with a Gemfile , specifiy in it the require version of rails?

Answer (score 23):

Do:

```
gem uninstall rails
gem uninstall railties
```

Followed by:

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.19
```

To check a rails version, directly do:

```
rails -v
```

**Another workaround:**

add following to your Gemfile:

```
 gem 'rails', '3.2.19'
```

and then run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 13):

Or you dont have to downgrade. You can always create a new rails app with a specific version(if that version is already installed)

```
rails _3.2.19_ new myApp
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not good approach to uninstall a global version of `Rails`. So just create a `Rails` app:

```
rails new app
```

then change `Rails` version in its **Gemfile**, and issue `bundle install`:

```
cd app
sed "s/'rails', '~> 4.2.0'/'rails', '~> 3.2.19'/" -i Gemfile
bundle install
```

Then, I believe, you should change all the dependent packages to older versions.

Comment: `sed` to change the rails version in the gemfile? :-|

Comment: @sixty4bit that is just text editor in that case as vim ;)