# Unable to create new app inn rails 6.0.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

/home/oem/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/messages/metadata.rb:17:in `wrap': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

i have rails 7.0.3 version and want to install rails *6.0.2.1*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082120/how-to-downgrade-my-rails-version Check this link out Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks for your respond, now i have uninstalled version 7.0.3 and installed 6.0.2.1   but same error

Comment: What command are you running that gave you the error? "Creating a new app" and "installing rails" are two different things, so I'm not 100% clear which part is failing. (Is it `gem install`, or `rails new`, or something else?)

Comment: Also, note that ruby `v3.0.0` was released in December **2020**, but rails `v6.0.2.1` was released in December **2019**. So, it's *possible* that rails `v6.0.2.1` *might* not be compatible with this ruby version. You may want to try using an older ruby version (`2.7.x`).

Comment: rails _6.0.2.1_ new app